# How do I connect Route 53 subdomain to EC2 load balancer? (SSL mismatch issue)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I want to have a subdomain (api.mysite.com) which makes calls to an EC2 classic load balancer (load-balancer-123456789.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com).  Everything is hosted on AWS, to (theoretically) make it as straightforward as possible.

I created a domain and subdomain in AWS Route 53, as per the instructions [here](https://dev.to/arswaw/create-a-subdomain-in-amazon-route53-in-2-minutes-3hf0), and created an "A" record in the subdomain that links to my load balancer as an alias.  That works fine, I can make calls to the load balancer through api.mysite.com, as long as I use HTTP.

But when I try to use HTTPS, I get ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.  If I try to open the API in a browser, the security icon says that it's "not secure".  I think the problem might be that the certificate is connected to the main domain (mysite.com) instead of the subdomain (api.mysite.com), but I can't figure out how to get it to resolve properly.

[This](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) SSL checking site shows the EC2 server itself (the one that the load balancer points to) and reports "Certificate not valid for domain name". It's an Ubuntu server, though I'm not sure if that should matter.

Comment: How did you setup your ssl certificates?

Comment: @Marcin Through AWS's Certificate Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSL certificate needs to specify the subdomain as well as the main domain.  The easiest way to do this is through AWS's Certificate Manager, by requesting a new certificate.

Make sure to specify each relevant domain and subdomain in the certificate (in this case, both mysite.com and api.mysite.com.)

After creating the certificate, go to the Load Balancer, open up the Listeners tab, and select the HTTPS port.  Then, change the SSL certificate for that port to the certificate that includes the relevant subdomain.  If you use AWS Certificate Manager, it can be selected from the dropdown menu.